# Combine Ranges to PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, union

I would like to combine two ranges that I have defined and save the to a pdf.  So far I have this:

```
Sub SaveAsPDF3()
'
' SaveAsPDF Macro
'
Dim pdfpath As String
Dim RP_Sum As Integer
Dim RP_Sum_Tot As Integer
Dim Summary As Range
Dim Critera As Range
Dim Summary_with_Criteria As Range
Set Criteria = Range("Criteria")
Set Summary = Range("Summary")


ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
pdfpath = Range("Ind_RP_Pdf")

RP_Sum = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Reports").Range("A10:A100"))
MsgBox (RP_Sum)
RP_Sum_Tot = 8 + RP_Sum + 2
'MsgBox (RP_Sum_Tot)
    Range(Cells(8, 1), Cells(RP_Sum_Tot, 11)).Name = "Summary"
Set Summary_with_Criteria = Application.Union(Summary, Criteria)

Range("Summary_with_Criteria").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=pdfpath, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

Range("Report_Learner").Select
End Sub
```

I get an error on the ExprotAsFixedformat line

Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: Just write: `Summary_with_Criteria.ExportAsFixedFormat`...  (Well there are some other syntax things too...)

Comment: thanks Chrismas007, that worked except it put the second range on a separate page

Comment: In that case, I would just copy each range to a temp sheet, save that sheet as PDF, then delete that sheet.